# Meteor force-ssl on a staging system without ssl cert?

Tags: ssl, meteor

Whenever I want to test my Meteor webpage on the staging server I have to uninstall the force-ssl package, since my staging server has no ssl cert. This sucks.

Force-ssl is disabled on localhost. How can I disable it on my staging system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Someone wrote a force-ssl package for exactly this problem:

https://atmospherejs.com/keyvan/my-force-ssl

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in [force-ssl](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/force-ssl/force_ssl_server.js) you can configure. But here are the options I see.

**Add a header:**
You might be routing your traffic through a Reverse Proxy or something. If that's so, you could just add the `x-forwarded-proto` header. You'd have to specify.

```
x-forwarded-proto: https
```

**Get An SSL Cert:**
You could also use a self-signed ssl-certificate or maybe wait a few weeks for [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to come out.